# Alfresco CMIS limit size and time query

Tags: alfresco, cmis

we are developing a front end integrated with Alfresco,
we are using CMIS protocol to execute queries against different istances of Alfresco, but we would like to set a limit to a maximum time and a maximum results that a query could give. Is this achievable with CMIS standard, or is only manageable with acl permissions in alfresco.global.properties (blocking lucene)? We would like not to touch these settings in Alfresco.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the AtomPub binding via HTTP directly and you are using HTTP GET, then you can add the the URL parameter `maxItems` to the query URL.

If you are using HTTP POST for the query, you have to add the `maxItems` parameters to the payload. See:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/cs01/cmis-spec-v1.0.html#_Toc243905541

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved our problem, we use HTTP GET, there is maxItems to set and that's it. Simple an easy.

Comment: We noticed that maxItems is considered only the second consecutive time it's triggered, like the first GET request isn't considering the value. Strange...We're still missing something..

Answer (score 4):

The CMIS specification makes no provision for limiting the maximum time it takes to return a query result. Neither does the OpenCMIS library, that I know of.

However, you can limit the number of search results that come back by setting maxItems. If you are using OpenCMIS you can do this by passing in an [OperationContext](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.8.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/OperationContext.html) on which you've called the setMaxItemsPerPage method.

Comment: We are actually not using Apache Chemistry libraries because we had difficulties retrieving nodes URL fetching queries against Alfresco. If there is a methos, we would be glad to know. Thanks

Comment: Limiting the result set works like this: ItemIterable<QueryResult> queryResult = session.query(query, false).getPage(maxItems);

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change a couple of configuration parameters in file repository.properties which is located in Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco. This parameters are:

system.acl.maxPermissionChecks
system.readpermissions.bulkfetchsize

You could set them to the value you want. Default values are set to 1000.